# What ports need to be open to use Murder on EC2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, capistrano, bittorrent

I'm trying to deploy a rails application locally to a cluster of EC2 machines using Twitter's Murder https://github.com/lg/murder/. I'm pushing it through Capistrano to a group of servers with a security group with the following TCP ports open:

```
22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0
25 (SMTP)   0.0.0.0/0
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0
143 (IMAP)  0.0.0.0/0
8998        0.0.0.0/0
6881-6889   0.0.0.0/0
```

The last port is the port that Murder is supposed to run the tracker on and the 6881-6889 is what BitTornado uses by default to download from.

While the Capistrano script runs, it gets to the "Peering..." stage and just sits. I SSH in to the servers that I'm pushing code to and they did get the code (shows up in /tmp) but the Murder script doesn't go beyond that.

If I open up all TCP ports (0-65535), it works just fine. I'm curious which other ports should be open in order for this to work as expected... without having to open up everything.

Does any one have any thoughts?

Comment: I'm having a somehwat related problem with using a gem to open an IMAP connection to gmail.  Works from bash, but rails hangs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, by default BitTornado picks a random port between 10000 and 60000 to listen to. These defaults can be changed in the download_bt1.py file in the BitTornado library. Look for the following lines:

```
('minport', 10000, 'minimum port to listen on, counts up if unavailable'),
('maxport', 60000, 'maximum port to listen on'),
('random_port', 1, 'whether to choose randomly inside the port range ' +
    'instead of counting up linearly'),
```

They're pretty self explanatory. Hope this helps.